# Android app shutdown

Tags: android, eclipse

When I run the application on some devices, so everything is ok, but the other devices that the user normally uses, but over time the application exits and after each opening writes Application unfortunately stopped working. After uninstalling and installing again only works about 10 minutes and then again the same error. When I reported the bug to play Google announced this message to me. Does anyone know what to do? Sorry for bad English.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at www.clientbook.cz.ClientBook.controlWebUrl(ClientBook.java:92)
at www.clientbook.cz.ClientBook.access$1(ClientBook.java:90)
at www.clientbook.cz.ClientBook$ClientBookClient.onPageFinished(ClientBook.java:239)
at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:332)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my function `controlWebUrl()`

```
private void controlWebUrl(String url) {
    //nastavení navigation
    if(!url.contains("/index/login") && !url.contains("/index/register") && !url.contains("/index/wait") && !url.contains("/index/active") && !url.contains("/index/forgotpassword")){
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(menuListLogin);
    login = true;
} else{
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(menuList);
    login = false;
}

if(url.contains("/index/login")){
    setTitle("Přihlášení");
} else if(url.contains("/index/register")){
    setTitle("Registrace");
} else if(url.contains("/index/forgotpassword")){
    setTitle("Zapomenuté heslo");
} else if(url.contains("/index/wait")){
    setTitle("Nepřišel vám e-mail ?");
} else if(url.contains("/index/profile")){
    setTitle("Můj profil");
} else if(url.contains("/clients/add")){
    setTitle("Přidat klienta");
} else if(url.contains("/clients/list")){
    setTitle("Seznam klientů");
} else if(url.contains("/clients/search")){
    setTitle("Hledat");
} else if(url.contains("/clients/map")){
    setTitle("Mapa klientů");
} else if(url.contains("/clients/show")){
    setTitle("Profil klienta");
} else if(url.contains("/clients/edit")){
    setTitle("Upravit klienta");
} else if(url.contains("/meetings")){
    setTitle("Schůzky");
} else if(url.contains("/forms")){
    setTitle("Dotazníky");
} else if(url.contains("/index/account")){
    setTitle("Můj účet");
} else if(url.contains("/index/settings")){
    setTitle("Nastavení");
} else if(url.contains("/index/search/type/sms")){
    setTitle("Hromadná SMS");
} else if(url.contains("/index/search/type/email")){
    setTitle("Hromadný E-mail");
} else if(url.contains("/index/search/type/dual")){
    setTitle("Hromadná SMS+E-mail");
} else if(url.contains("/index/search/type/history")){
    setTitle("Historie Hromadného rozesílání");
}  else {
    setTitle("ClientBook.cz");
}
```

}

Where is the problem? Function must have a return?

This is WebViewClient

```
private class ClientBookClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url)
    {           
           if (!loadingFinished) {
               redirect = true;
            }

        loadingFinished = false;
        webview.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView webview, String url, Bitmap favicon){
        loadingFinished = false;
    }


    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView webview, String url) {
        controlWebUrl(mWebView.getUrl());
        if(!redirect){
            loadingFinished = true;
         }

         if(loadingFinished && !redirect && findViewById(R.id.connect).getVisibility() == View.GONE){
            findViewById(R.id.load_pb).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.load_text).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.connect).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         } else{
             if(findViewById(R.id.connect).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                 findViewById(R.id.load_pb).setVisibility(View.GONE);
             }
            redirect = false; 
            //error = false;
         }             


    }

    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCod,String description, String failingUrl) {
        if(errorCod == -1){
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else if(errorCod == -2){
            mWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            TextView error_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.load_text);
            error_text.setText("Neumím pracovat bez internetu..");
            error_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
            findViewById(R.id.connect).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: You have a null pointer in ClientBook in the method controlWebUrl() at line 92.

Comment: Either your url or your mDrawerList is null.

Answer (score 0):

On your phone, in the menu, enable `Developer Options|Don't Save Activities` so that every time you put your `Activity` in background it gets destroyed. Then put your app in the background from your `ClientBook` activity (or whatever it is) and then restore. You will probably have that exception and will be able to debug.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the problem is the life cycle of your variables. While your app is asleep, the OS goes in and does some memory freeing.

You can do some null checks in your onResume() to help catch this. Essentially you want to check that your app hasn't been 'cleaned up' while it was asleep.

You can do something like this:

```
protected void onResume(){      
    super.onResume();

    if(important_val == null){
        initialize_app();
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is important value ? i use some tutorial for write this app. The problem is probably in webViewClient when i checking loading url and then showing loading progressbar or webView. This is my code. (up in question)

Comment: Whatever value that is getting getting checked here: ClientBook.java:92. If I was to hazard a guess, I would say url or whatever is being passed in as url.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, after you restart the application, there is no exist variable URL. Therefore, the condition if (url! = ..) Fails and the application fails?

Answer (score 0):

I added a condition to function controlWebUrl()

```
private void controlWebUrl(String url) {
    if(url!=null){
    //nastavení navigation
    if(!url.contains("/index/login") && !url.contains("/index/register") && !url.contains("/index/wait") && !url.contains("/index/active") && !url.contains("/index/forgotpassword")){
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(menuListLogin);
        login = true;
    } else{
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(menuList);
        login = false;
    }

    if(url.contains("/index/login")){
        setTitle("Přihlášení");
    } else if(url.contains("/index/register")){
        setTitle("Registrace");
    } else if(url.contains("/index/forgotpassword")){
        setTitle("Zapomenuté heslo");
    } else if(url.contains("/index/wait")){
        setTitle("Nepřišel vám e-mail ?");
    } else if(url.contains("/index/profile")){
        setTitle("Můj profil");
    } else if(url.contains("/clients/add")){
        setTitle("Přidat klienta");
    } else if(url.contains("/clients/list")){
        setTitle("Seznam klientů");
    } else if(url.contains("/clients/search")){
        setTitle("Hledat");
    } else if(url.contains("/clients/map")){
        setTitle("Mapa klientů");
    } else if(url.contains("/clients/show")){
        setTitle("Profil klienta");
    } else if(url.contains("/clients/edit")){
        setTitle("Upravit klienta");
    } else if(url.contains("/meetings")){
        setTitle("Schůzky");
    } else if(url.contains("/forms")){
        setTitle("Dotazníky");
    } else if(url.contains("/index/account")){
        setTitle("Můj účet");
    } else if(url.contains("/index/settings")){
        setTitle("Nastavení");
    } else if(url.contains("/index/search/type/sms")){
        setTitle("Hromadná SMS");
    } else if(url.contains("/index/search/type/email")){
        setTitle("Hromadný E-mail");
    } else if(url.contains("/index/search/type/dual")){
        setTitle("Hromadná SMS+E-mail");
    } else if(url.contains("/index/search/type/history")){
        setTitle("Historie Hromadného rozesílání");
    }  else {
        setTitle("ClientBook.cz");
    }

    } else{
        return;
    }


}
```

and yet it seems to be working. But i dont know what is a problem with life cycle and what is the problem when the application sleeping. So thanks for help :)